# I'm getting a Parser Error: Expected token Comma got 'Return' return contributions.length - 1; ^

Tags: solidity, tokens

```
function contribute()
    public 
    inState(State.Fundraising)
    isMinimum()
    iinMultipleOfPrice() payable returns (uint256){

        uint256 amountInWei = msg.value;

        contributions.push(
            Contribution({amount: msg.value, contributor: msg.sender})
            );
        totalRaised += msg.value;
        currentBalance = totalRaised;
        if(fundingMaximumTargetInwei !=0){
            tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amountInWei/priceInWei);

        } else {
            tokenReward.mintToken(msg.sender, amountInWei/priceInWei);

        }   

        (LogFundingSuccessful(msg.sender, msg.value, totalRaised)

        //Check if funding is completed & pay the beneficiary accordingly

        return contributions.length - 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(LogFundingSuccessful(msg.sender, msg.value, totalRaised)
```

This line is wrong, I can assume that LogFundingSucceessful is an event, so you will probably need something like this.

> LogFundingSuccessful(msg.sender, msg.value, totalRaised);

Let me highlights the mistakes, the parentheses in the beginning are not necessary and you're also missing a semi colon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This line is definitely not correct:

```
       (LogFundingSuccessful(msg.sender, msg.value, totalRaised)
```

The opening parenthesis is not required, and you need a terminating `;`.

Without the whole code it's difficult to see what other issues there may be. If you continue to have problems, then post the whole thing.